# How to share the display of a laptop with 8 more laptops without flicker?

Tags: networking, windows-10, laptop, hdmi

I want to have 9 laptops' screens shared. so that one of them is master and the other ones see what is done in it.

I thought about teaching softwares such as [NetSupport School](http://www.netsupportschool.com/index.asp) which it is possible to use LAN cables to connect many computers to each other.
but I have seen the display of a client computer that was connected to such a system. It flickered.

Or is there any alternative?

By master I mean the laptop whose actions are seen.
And by client or slave I mean those which see the activities of master laptop.

GiantTree suggested to setup a TeamViewer meeting. Having no local internet connection, how can I manually wire the lap tops using LAN cables to achieve a network to use TeamViewer?

My own idea is using 'bus' topology. then how would the configurations be?

---

edit: In response to Daniel B, HDMI idea doesn't work. so I omitted those parts.

Comment: You could use TeamViewer and arrange a "Meeting" so that everyone can see what is done on the Master but can't interact with it (there are multiple ways to make this possible with TeamViewer).

Comment: How would that ever work with HDMI? Laptops usually don’t have HDMI input connectors, only output. // Please describe your use case in greater detail. What would happen on the master screen? Something like a PowerPoint presentation? Video playback? Or perhaps something like video games?

Comment: @DanielB PowerPoint. but not presentation. the edit screen in which you arrange the slides and make the presentation. And they all have one HDMI sockets (one per laptop)

Comment: Yes, those are outputs. They can’t be used as inputs.

Comment: @GiantTree yes but wouldn't that be slow? and flicker is a concern.

Comment: You could  possibly give this Idea a go Using [VLC Media Player](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwifp9LnmqTNAhVlF8AKHXICC1oQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.videolan.org%2Fvlc%2Findex.html&usg=AFQjCNGBhuuzYHOSa3E8AKS6WdxI_OOjYQ&sig2=0WlxPADX2aV1Qf9S8WFmkw&bvm=bv.124272578,d.d24) here is a link to the [Tutorial](https://software.grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=14625) on setup.

Comment: Oh yeah and by flickering do you perhaps mean stuttering or perhaps choppy movements? Because it’s really rather impossible otherwise.